# WSO2 Change default database to MySql

Tags: mysql, wso2

I have followed https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Installing+and+Configuring+the+Databases this document for changing default  database to mysql in api manager. Once i am done with  all changes and i start server using "wso2server.sh" file it will discard all changes in file and default configuration of h2 database will replace new configuration for MySql.

Comment: what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the problem description it looks like you are using API Manager 3.0.0. From v3.0.0 onwards, you have a deployment.toml file which resides in repository/conf location. The users are expected to change only this file by going forward. Please refer https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/install-and-setup/setting-up-databases/changing-default-databases/changing-to-mysql/